# Am having trouble moving code into a separate function

Tags: swift, uikit, safearealayoutguide

From within my GameViewController's **viewDidLoad()** function I do two things:

1- I create a sub UIVIew, myView, which is added to the main view,

2- I call my function, addConstraints, which is in the GameViewController's code.

When I create GameScene, **self.myView.frame.width** & **self.myView.frame.height** contain the correct values, and abide by the safeAreaLayout guides.

I want to make my code clearer, so I've moved the addConstraints function to a separate file. But when I run my app that way **self.myView.frame.width** & **self.myView.frame.height** are zero.

So am curious if I am somehow translating the function incorrectly, or maybe this is something I can't move outside of the main code?

The first block is the original code, the 2nd is the function

```
//located with GameViewControl    
private func addConstraints(){
        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
        
        constraints.append(myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor))
        constraints.append(myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor))
        constraints.append(myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor))
        constraints.append(myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
```

translated into a function

```
//called from GameViewControl
    createConstraints(view: myView)
    ....
        
//located outside of GameViewControl
func createConstraints(view: UIView) {
    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
                    
    constraints.append(view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor))
    constraints.append(view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor))
    constraints.append(view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor))
    constraints.append(view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))
                    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```

And here is the full file of GameViewControl

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let myView : UIView = {
        let myView = UIView()
        setViewAttributes(view: myView)
        return myView
    }()

    private func addConstraints(){
         var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        //add
         constraints.append(myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor))
         constraints.append(myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor))
         constraints.append(myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor))
         constraints.append(myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))
        
        //activate
         NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
     }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        #if DEBUG
            print ("viewDidLoad")
        #endif
        
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            getScreenDimensions (screen: &screenDims)
            view.addSubview(myView)
            addConstraints()

            var scene : GameScene!
            DispatchQueue.main.async { scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: self.myView.frame.width, height: self.myView.frame.width))
                scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
                scene.backgroundColor = .clear
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
                view.isHidden = false
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder    = true
            view.showsFPS               = true
            view.showsNodeCount         = true
            view.showsPhysics           = true
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        #if DEBUG
            print ("GVC viewDidLayoutSubviews")
        #endif

        myGlobalVars.sceneRect = view.frame
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            myGlobalVars.topSafeArea    = view.safeAreaInsets.top
            myGlobalVars.bottomSafeArea = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        } else {
            myGlobalVars.topSafeArea    = topLayoutGuide.length
            myGlobalVars.bottomSafeArea = bottomLayoutGuide.length
        }
    }
    
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        #if DEBUG
            print ("shouldAutorotate")
        #endif
        return false
    }
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        #if DEBUG
            print ("supportedInterfaceOrientations")
        #endif
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        #if DEBUG
            print ("prefersStatusBarHidden")
        #endif
        return false
    }
}
```

The call to function **setViewAttributes** does pass the view to a function, and I have verified that that function is working.

```
func setViewAttributes(view: UIView)
{
    view.alpha                = 0.0
    view.frame.size.height    = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height
    view.frame.size.width     = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.width
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor      = .clear
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After going through the code, over and over I realized I was calling the safeAreaLayout routine *before* **viewDidLayoutSubviews**. Now I can move my call to a function and it works.  Now I'd love to know why it was working before, when I was calling it prematurely. But maybe I should be grateful that I found a substantial error.

So now my code looks the same as the code in the OP, except every call regarding screen dimensions, and safeAreaLayout, are done in the **viewDidLayoutSubviews** function.

*And addConstraints is now an external function*

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    getScreenDimensions (screen: &screenDims)
    view.addSubview(myView)
    addConstraints()
    myGlobalVars.sceneRect = view.frame
    createConstraints(view: myView)
    
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        myGlobalVars.topSafeArea    = view.safeAreaInsets.top
        myGlobalVars.bottomSafeArea = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    } else {
        myGlobalVars.topSafeArea    = topLayoutGuide.length
        myGlobalVars.bottomSafeArea = bottomLayoutGuide.length
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just move this kind of function because the `view` variable inside it refers to `GameViewController.view`.

If you want to do a refactor like this you can move this method to an extension and call it inside your `GameViewController`.

```
public extension UIView {
    func createConstraints() {
        guard let superview = superview else { return }

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
                        
        constraints.append(leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor))
        constraints.append(trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor))
        constraints.append(bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor))
        constraints.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor))
                        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

And then instead of calling `addConstraints()` in `viewDidLoad()` you should call `myView.createConstraints()`. It should work the same as before.

> You can read more about extension from [Extensions — The Swift
> Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html).

> And also you should read this too [Programmatically Creating
> Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)

Comment: Just to make sure, I was, trying, to pass the view into the function. Tried it directly, and as a reference.

Comment: There is a function in there that already passes the view with no problem.  Just updated the OP

Comment: You better use constraints instead of setting frame. And extensions is a good way for this kind solutions. It's called Auto Layout yet another reading for you :)

Comment: Am not using storyboard. Technically I can move from this, by leaving my original code.  It's more of a "why can't I put this in a function properly" question.

Comment: You can. But you're trying to add constraint from view to view. Second one should be superview. view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor)

Comment: Am answering my own question. But please if you see anything wrong in the answer feel free to comment.